# Accuracy of Duration column in Trace ouput

Tags: sql-server-2005, datetime, trace

I have saved a trace output from SS2005 to a table.  The smallest value contained in the Duration column is 976.  Since this column is displaying microseconds this equates to 0.976 milliseconds.  Since DATATIME is only accurate to 3.33 milliseconds I thought 3330 microseconds was the smallest time increment discernible to SS and the smallest value I would see in the Duration column.  Is this not correct or am I misinterpreting the output?

Comment: Wow, there is a lot of confusion about microseconds and milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Accuracy Rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds

from here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx

Comment: Yes they are rounded.  That is why all DATETIME fields end in 0,3, or 7.  But how can the Duration column display a value that is LESS than 3.33 ms?